# How to use old Apple remote with Apple TV

Tags: macbook-pro, appletv, remote-control

I have an old white infrared Apple remote for a 2008 Macbook. I lost my apple TV remote and can't get passed the setup screen. I can see that the Macbook remote is noticed by the Apple TV because the light blinks when I use it, but it doesn't control anything. Is there a way to pair it? At least temporarily so I can use the Remote app?

Answer (score 1):

On the white remote, you must first press and hold the Menu and Previous/Rewind buttons for 6 seconds.  This will clear out any old paired remote.
Then, press and hold the Menu and Next/Fast-forward buttons for 6 seconds.  This will pair with your remote.

(Source: [Apple support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201254))

Comment: Hmm. I tried that. It's definitely recognizing the remote. The Apple TV light starts blinking rapidly but I still can't control it.

Comment: I updated the answer.  You may have to clear the old pairing first.  I tried this with an old remote I had lying around, and it would not work until the old pairing was removed.  Oddly enough, doing the inverse with the silver remote still allowed both remotes to control the Apple TV.  YMMV.